# Chinese software on PC - creating a silo?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have use certain software for my job and most of it is Chinese software. 
Very often, the Chinese clients could easily (some might say more easily) use software like Skype but choose to use these obscure software packages. Of course, this may be innocuous, but my suspicions remain.

Therefore, does anyone know of a way of installing a piece of software on Windows so that it runs in a kind of silo, i.e. it can't get access to other elements. Would simply creating a new Windows login and installing the software on that specific login work? Can software installed on one login access data held on another login's area?

Any insight/ideas would be gratefully received!

Comment: Docker or a virtual machine would suffice this, Have you tried any of those?

Comment: Windows 10 v1909 has sandbox support, a windows environment that destroys itself after use and keeps things isolated.

Comment: I caution relaying entirely on Windows Sandbox to run potentially malicious programs.  I watched a YouTube video recently, on a channel that tests security software, against thousands of payloads.  *In this particular video, Windows Sandbox allowed malicious software, to infect the host OS.*  However, it's important to point out the the author was running a VM which only had Windows Defender installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is this old, well-known, saying in the computer industry: If someone has physical access to the computer it is by definition no longer secure.
Well: All software installed on the computer has physical access.
Anything that is installed in Windows potentially will have full access to the whole computer.
There is no safety if it is on the same Windows installation.

You will have to setup a separate computer (or a virtual machine) for that software.

Comment: -1 Windows 10 v1909 has Sandbox support which is essentially what OP asks.

Comment: @LPChip I know that, but the capabilities of that sandbox are fairly limited (not all applications work with it, it is mainly intended for portable apps, that don't require an installation) and frankly... At this point nobody really knows how secure it really is. It is just too new. It is better than nothing, but no substitute for a really isolated system in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like you can only use sandbox on a Pro or Ultimate edition of Windows, and I have the lowly free-upgrade-from-Windows-7 edition :-(

Comment: @Hashamyim your post lacks that information. The more information we have to help you, the more precise our answer will be.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that you needed Pro/Ultimate until I knew that Sandbox existed, and that only happened due to this thread. BUT! It turns out that I do have Windows 10 Pro but the Sandbox activation option wasn't avaolable because virtualisation wasn't enabled on the Bios. Done and done and now Sandbox is in the process of being installed. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Hashamyim - Ultimate is no longer an edition of Windows.  I personally would not trust Windows Sandbox to run potentially malicious software packages